# IFrame in webdriver. Typing in RTE

Tags: c#, iframe, selenium, webdriver, rich-text-editor

I have a Rich Text Editor on my page, and some text needed to be typed in there. I wrote a solution but it seems to only work intermittently. Here is what I've already tried:

```
        var iframe = _driver.SwitchTo().Frame(Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath)));
        var editor = iframe.FindElement(By.XPath("//*"));
        for (var i = 1; _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*")).Text == String.Empty; i++)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    editor.SendKeys(text);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    editor.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
                    editor.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);
                    editor.SendKeys(text);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    editor.Click();
                    editor.SendKeys(text);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    throw new Exception("Rich Text Editor can't be reached");
            }
            editor.SendKeys(text);
```

In loop I check if text is typed. If it is not I try different cases.
Additionally, if I try to execute **editor.Clear();** I permanently get an error "Element must be user-editable in order to clear it." I can type (time to time), but cannot clear (permanently).
So, the question is how to stabilize this code?

Comment: What type exception it is throwing randomly ?
Before doing any operation make sure that element is available in DOM.

Are you able to clear the content manually in Rich Text Editor?

Comment: It is just silently not typing, no exception caused by this. Form is fully interactive manually.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. It works through DOM. currentInstance get focused text area, thats why I have click method first.

```
editor.Click();
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) _driver;
js.ExecuteScript("CKEDITOR.currentInstance.insertText('text')")
```

Comment: also there is window.frames[0] but somehow that didn't work for me.