# Webdriver switching to overlay window

Tags: webdriver, frame

Webdriver unable to locate object in an overlay.

I am trying to switch to frame and click on an object in the frame. but i am not able to do it.

i tried all the "id" from the below HTML. but i am not finding it.

Please help me

below is the code

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("fancybox-outer")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("ContactSaveConfirmYes_Button"))).click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Here is the HTML:

I want to click on "Yes" button in this overlay.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body onload="showLossHistoryLink();  contactTypeDisplay();openInsuredContact();showErrorMessages();checkInjuryFields();">
<div class="billboardWindow124">
<div id="fancybox-tmp" style="padding: 50px;"/>
<div id="fancybox-loading" style="display: none;">
<div id="fancybox-overlay" style="background-color: rgb(119, 119, 119); opacity: 0.2;  cursor: auto; height: 850px; display: block;"/>
<div id="fancybox-wrap" style="width: 319px; height: auto; top: 574px; left: 452px; display: block;"> 
<div id="fancybox-outer">
<div id="fancybox-bg-n" class="fancybox-bg"/>
<div id="fancybox-bg-ne" class="fancybox-bg"/>
<div id="fancybox-bg-e" class="fancybox-bg"/>
<div id="fancybox-bg-se" class="fancybox-bg"/>
<div id="fancybox-bg-s" class="fancybox-bg"/>
<div id="fancybox-bg-sw" class="fancybox-bg"/>
<div id="fancybox-bg-w" class="fancybox-bg"/>
<div id="fancybox-bg-nw" class="fancybox-bg"/>
<div id="fancybox-content" style="border-width: 10px; width: 299px; height: auto;">
<div style="width:auto;height:auto;overflow: auto;position:relative;">
<form id="formSaveContact" action="#">
<div id="confirmSaveContact" class="confirmSaveContact">
<p>Are you sure you want to save this contact?</p>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="policyType"/>
<input id="yesBtn2" type="image" src="img/eng-usa/button_yes.jpg" value="yes"/>
<input id="noBtn2" type="image" src="img/eng-usa/button_no.jpg" value="no"/>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<a id="fancybox-close"/>
<div id="fancybox-title" class="" style="display: none;"/>
<a id="fancybox-left" href="javascript:;">
<a id="fancybox-right" href="javascript:;">
</div>
</div>
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden-accessible"/>
</body>
</html>**
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue to type in iframe. Try my solution if js suits you.

[IFrame in webdriver. Typing in RTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508125/iframe-in-webdriver-typing-in-rte)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't apply your concept because the issue was different. I have mentioned it in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me...i am not sure whether this will work for others...based on UI designer.

Overlay objects are considered as Driver and it is not considered as frame.

So no need to switch to frame and find out the object...instead find the object without switching.

Aariff

Answer (score 0):

```
@driver.switch_to.window( @driver.window_handles.last ){

@driver.find_elemnt(:id,name)
@driver.find_elemnt(:id,age)

@driver.find_elemnt(:id,eid)
@driver.find_elemnt(:id,company)

}
```